# How does drawing work when a JPanel is inside a JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, paintcomponent

So I have a `JPanel` inside a `JScrollPane` (let's call them panel and pane for reference)
So I added created the pane as so :

```
JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```

Then I added my pane to the frame.
So now I want to draw in my panel. I first tried doing this by overriding the `paintComponent` method in my panel class. I thought that my whole panel would be drawn and then I would be able to scroll through it because I added the panel to the pane. But every time I move the bar, it keeps trying to redraw. Is my logic not right? Should I be drawing in another manner?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can't solve a problem we can't see or reproduce.

Comment: can you add some code?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that my whole panel would be drawn and then I would be able to scroll through it because I added the panel to the pane. But every time I move the bar, it keeps trying to redraw.

This is just how `JScrollPane`s work, see the documentation for [`JViewport`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html) for a description of the algorithm.

If your drawing algorithm involves heavy processing, or you otherwise want to avoid having to redraw the panel so frequently, you can [draw to an `BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawonimage.html) instead, and then use `drawImage()` from Graphics2d to draw the panel more efficiently on scroll updates.